# Logs getting saved in prior one day file using Log4j

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j

I am using Log4j(1.2.16) for logging purpose.
Configured following properties

```
log4j.appender.SERVICE_LOGGER=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SERVICE_LOGGER.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

Now, I have one file with 2015-06-11 date and another one is 2015-06-12, When I go on using my application, some of the logs saved in 2015-06-11 file whereas current date is 2015-06-12. This is very confusing for me as I not able to understand how partial logs goes in one day prior files? And this happens with all dates. Time zone of server is fine. Also I have checked with https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-116 link, but this is not the case for me.

Additionally, This works fine when we had only one context on Tomcat. Now we have two different context(configured in `server.xml`) on single tomcat server.

Is any one have faced this scenario? Please let me know if any extra configuration required.

Comment: What about the server time itself but not timezone?

Comment: Yes. Server time too OK.